# returning to an address on the stack

Tags: assembly, buffer-overflow

I am working on a project for school that deals with overflowing buffers (the buffer overflow bomb) I am sure many of you have done it or heard of it.  I am not looking for how to do it but just have a general Question concerning returns.  Is it possible to return to an address on the stack?  I only ask because this seems like the most logical way to solve the phase but it keeps segfaulting and this occurs commonly when trying to access memory outside of your "sandbox" but I would think the stack would be accessible to my program and since it's not really a common question to look up I figured someone on here might know

I should mention the program was designed to allow you to execute code from the stack

Thanks

Comment: It is a loophole that's been closed for a while already.  Known as "DEP (data execution prevention)" and the "NX (no execute) bit".  It prevents the memory pages that map the stack from having executable code.  You'll have to turn that off to have any hope of actually making this work.  Or dig up a really old machine.  Ask at superuser.com, OS config isn't on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an x86, to return to a location *in* the stack:

```
  LEA   EAX, offset[ESP]
  JMP   EAX
```

as others have noted, data execution prevention may prevent the processor
from actually executing in the stack area once the JMP has executed.

To return to a location whose address is *specified in the stack*:

```
  JMP   offset[ESP]
```

Similarly, if the target location is in "data pages", DEP will prevent execution.
(You can call Windows and remove DEP on that data; I'm not sure you can
do that for the stack.)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can return to address *in* stack. But if stack memory is not executable (depends on CPU capabilities and OS), memory access violation exception will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is a combination of the processors instruction set and a calling convention that a compiler uses.  Some processors will only return using addresses on the stack, others might only be able to use addresses in other registers, and some it is up to the programmer.  Naturally you could if you wanted pop an address of the stack fora  register only branch type processor, or put an address on the stack from a register for a stack only type processor.

Your older designs like the x86 would normally have the call instruction place the return address on the stack and the return instruction pull the return address off of the stack to use it.  With x86 the CS may be on the stack as well.  Processors in this category will often place the flags on the stack for an interrupt and return from interrupt pops the flags and the return address.

Based on the processors rules you choose how you return from a function, a convention is made so that all functions use the same rules and the compiler uses that convention.

You need to know the processor you are using a little better and the calling convention you are trying to use or exploit.